# Probability distribution of the decay of a single radioactive nucleus

Tags: probability, radioactivity

A single radioactive nucleus has a constant probability to decay at any moment. Does this imply that the decay of the particle has a uniform probability distribution from the point in time of the particle's creation to a point infinitely far away in the future?

If this is the case, how is this possible if it is not possible to have a uniform probability distribution over an infinite domain (for example, over the whole number line)?

Comment: A probability distribution is the result of many repeatable events. It's not the result of a single, non-repeatable event.

Comment: Hi. There's a good description of how the probabilities change with time in David Zaslavsky's answer to the question I've linked.